# Download all sub html pages of parent page that is 404 not found?

Tags: wget

Hello I'm learning CS50 and would like to download all problem sets offline. Each problem appears as a single html page like

```
http://docs.cs50.net/problems/recover/recover.html
http://docs.cs50.net/problems/fifteen/fifteen.html
```

while the parent page

```
http://docs.cs50.net/problems/
```

returns a **404** error.

How can I download all sub html pages then? I've tried `wget` and `httrack` but failed. Thanks!

Comment: If there isn't a page that has a list of all the links on it, then I don't think there is anything you can easily do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cant given the information given.

`http://docs.cs50.net/problems/` is not a web page, it is a URL to a folder, which has no default webpage inside of it - typically `index.html` or `default.html`.  Therefore, the webserver has nothing to display and gives the 404 error.  In addition to that, directory browsing is disabled on the web server, as you do not see the `recover`, `fifteen`, etc. subfolders.   You can test this by trying [http://docs.cs50.net/problems/recover](http://docs.cs50.net/problems/recover/)
 and getting the same 404 error.

Unless there is a webpage that references as all the subtopics as links, `WGET`, or any other similar program, will not be able to find the webpages.  However, there is likely to be one, or how else would you know those pages exist?  If you find that page, you would be good to go, as you and follow the links.